# comparison by wrapper type in julia

Tags: types, julia

I have a bunch of parametric singleton structs with a hierarchy, i need to stablish a comparison operation to find if a list of those singletons is "unique". where the comparison is between the main (o wrapper) types, ignoring the parametric ones, using `Array` and `Tuple` types and and the desired function `myequal`:

```
myequal(Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,2}) #true, because both are Arrays
myequal(Array{Int64,1},Tuple{Int64,Int64}) #false
```

One option to define myequal is using the internal fields of the type

```
function myequal(a::Type,b::Type)
  ta = a.name
  tb = b.name
  return ta == tb
end
```

But using internal undocumented fields is not a recommended practice. Is there a canonical way to do this?

Comment: Do _all_ `Array{Int64,N} where N` types compare equal with this function? And what about two `Tuple` arguments--would those also compare equal? Your implementation seems to suggest so.

Comment: Yeah, basically is more strict than isequal,as the main use is comparing singletons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nameof(myType)` returns a `Symbol`  with the type name which is exactly what you need.

```
julia> nameof(Vector{Int})
:Array

julia> nameof(Matrix{Float64})
:Array
```

Now you can use those `Symbol`s for comparison.